# JSF+Primefaces p:ajax on p:selectOneMenu not firing

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dropdown that holds an account number and two date fields. I want to reset the date fields if I change the value of the dropdown. I also have a search button that make a query using these fields (account #, from date, to date).

```
<fieldset>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="account_search" value="#{accountHistoryBean.account}" converter="accountConverter">
        <f:attribute name="itemsList" value="#{accountHistoryBean.userAccounts}"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{accountHistoryBean.userAccounts}" var="account" itemLabel="#{account.number}" itemValue="#{account}"/> 
        <p:ajax update="start_date_search, end_date_search" event="change" actionListener="#{accountHistoryBean.resetDates}" process="account_search"/> 
    </p:selectOneMenu>
<fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <p:calendar value="#{accountHistoryBean.fromDate}" id="start_date_search" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <p:calendar value="#{accountHistoryBean.toDate}" id="end_date_search" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
</fieldset>



<fieldset>
    <p:commandLink styleClass="regular_button" action="#{accountHistoryBean.search}" update=":search :accountHistoryList :accountHistoryList:accountHistTable" >
        <span>#{msj.search}</span>
     </p:commandLink>
 </fieldset>
```

If I do the following:

1. Change "from Date" and "to Date" fields
2. Change account field (dropdown with ajax).

Then the dates are resetted to their default value.

But if I do the following:

1. Change "from Date" and "to Date" fields to DATEX AND DATEY
2. Press search
3. Change "from Date" and "to Date" fields to DATEX2 AND DATEY2
4. Change account field (dropdown with ajax).

Then it changes the Date field to DATEX and DATEY (not the default values).

The methods in the Bean are the following:

```
public void resetDates()
{
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    //By default set toDate as 3/3
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);
    toDate = calendar.getTime();
    //By default fromDate is one month earlier
    calendar.setTime(toDate);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    fromDate = calendar.getTime();
}

public String search(){
    //Just update the filters
    lazyDataEntityModel.setUpdateData(true);
    return null;
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Is your listener method invoked in step 4? Did you verify it with a debugger?

Comment: I did something similar and I found I made a mistake in the jsf converter, but the error message never displayed.
Did you checked the jsf converter for `account`?

Comment: @MattHandy my listener is not being invoked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed

```
<p:ajax update="start_date_search, end_date_search" 
        event="change" 
        actionListener="#{accountHistoryBean.resetDates}"
        process="account_search"/>
```

For

```
<p:ajax update="start_date_search, end_date_search" 
        event="change"
        listener="#{accountHistoryBean.resetDates}" 
        process="account_search"/>
```

and it worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is about the Converter. Check the value property in the h:selectOneMenu!! Is not mapped properly. If you still have doubts set immediate="true" so no converter or validator will do their job. That´s what I did, and worked.....after 4 - 6 hours....:|

Thanks you about the converter idea, that was the tip that provided me the right answer.